# How to catch IOException in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, filewriter, file-writing

I'm trying to write data into a text file by pressing a button in JavaFx. The only problem, however is when I try to use the statement, "throws IOException" in my button processing method, things don't seem to work. Here is my code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class testingFx extends Application{
//Create controls
private Button write;
private Scene main;
private Button Exit;
private Scene sceneMain; 
private File records;
private FileWriter fw;

public static void main(String[] args){
   launch(args);
 }

@Override

public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{

  //Create new file
  records = new File("records.txt");
  records.createNewFile();
  //Create FileWriter
  fw = new FileWriter(records);

  //Create root, format controls, scene, etc...
  Group root = new Group();
  write = new Button();
  write.setText("Write");
  write.setOnAction(this::processButtonPress);
  root.getChildren().addAll(write);
  main = new Scene(root,300,300);
  stage.setScene(main);
  stage.show();
}
   public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
   if (event.getSource() == write){
        //On button press write to file
        fw.write("Testing file writing");
        //Close filewriter
        fw.close();
     }
  }
}
```

I've tried to find the answer online but the way I was taught to handle a button press differs from most others examples (the section that says (this::processButtonPress)). I'm not sure if using a try/catch statement would help me here as I don't any experience with those, forgive me. The error I specifically am getting is "error: incompatible thrown types IOException in method reference". Thank you for your help.

I've tried to make this question on topic and easy to address. Please let me know if there are any glaring issues.

Comment: You have to deal with the IOException inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need to use a try/catch statement to catch an exception.

If you update the method as I have shown, you will catch the exception.

You then need to add code to handle the exception, so the program will continue successfully.

```
    public void processButtonPress(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == write) {
            try {
                // On button press write to file
                fw.write("Testing file writing");
                // Close filewriter
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                // Code to handle goes here...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works brilliantly! I'll have to look into these statements more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to write good code without exception handling. Just incase you were wondering, the code in the try block will run line by line until an exception it thrown. Once it is thrown, all additional code in the try block will be skipped. Only code in the catch block will execute.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why IOException cannot be in the throws clause of the action handler.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to have automatic closing of your writer.

Also you may implement action handler like this:

```
write.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (event.getSource() == write) {
        try {
            try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(records)) {
                //On button press write to file
                fw.write("Testing file writing");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO process the exception properly
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```